# Extract .tar.gz inside a .tar file

Tags: bash, shell-script, tar, compression

I have a double-compressed file (`.tar.gz` inside a `.tar`) and i would like to know if there is any way to automatically extract it from a bash script. I tried two approaches:

```bsh
tar -xf $1 #the first .tar file is passed as argument to the bash script
tar -xf /home/user/working_dir/file_inside.tar.gz #passing the absolute path to the file assuming the .tar file was extracted as expected.
```

```bsh
tar -xf $1 | tar -xf `xargs`
```

But i get the error: `tar: /file_inside.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you know relative filename of intermediate file, try

```
tar -xf $1 -O path/to/file.tar.gz | tar xf -
```

where

> ```
>    -O, --to-stdout
>           Extract files to standard output.
> ```

1. you might need `-z` flag in second tar
2. please note that `-` is synonym for stdin, maybe that what you meant (`tar -xf $1 | tar -xf xargs` (*) ) ?

   ```
   tar -xf $1 | tar -xf -
   ```

(*) xargs is backquoted

---

If you feel adventurous, you can also try option `--to-command=COMMAND`

```
tar -xf $1 --to-command="tar -xzf -" path/to/file
```

1. I advise to test before going "production"
2. Do not use absolute path